# Logarithms with trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

My class is going to have an exam tomorrow, but we can't figure out how to solve such equations.

$$\log_{\ \large tg(x)} \sqrt{\sin(x)^2 - 5/12} < 1 $$

We tried to transform $1$ to $\log_{\ \large tg(x)} tg(x)$ and solve it as

$$\sqrt{\sin(x)^2 - 5/12} < tg(x)$$

But we don't know how to continue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $tg(x)$?

Comment: tangent [message too short]

Comment: What is $[a,b]$? An interval?

Comment: The step you have taken is only valid if $\log \tan x >0$. If it is negative, the inequality will reverse. And you must exclude the possibility that it is zero.

Comment: @MPW Someone just edited it, I wasn't sure how to express it.

Answer (score 1):

Square both sides, replace $\tan x$ with $\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ , and $\cos^2x$ with $1-\sin^2x$.